# Change password procedure PLSQL using IN and OUT parameters

Tags: authentication, plsql, passwords, procedure

Good evening!

I’m trying to make a stored procedure in PLSQL where I can change a users password. I want to check if the current password is correct after which I will either update the users password or else print an error. What I’ve come up with so far is the following code. I’m struggling with the different parameters and how to use them to check whether the password is correct or not. Can somebody give me a tip? Any advice is appreciated!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHANGE_PWD (
    P_USERNAME   IN     USERS.USERNAME%TYPE,
    P_OLD_PW     IN     USERS.PASSWORD%TYPE,
    P_NEW_PW     IN     USERS.PASSWORD%TYPE,
    P_SUCCES        OUT BOOLEAN)
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT USERS.PASSWORD
      INTO P_OLD_PW
      FROM USERS
     WHERE USERS.USERNAME = p_username;

    IF p_old_pw = USERS.PASSWORD
    THEN
        UPDATE USERS
           SET PASSWORD = p_new_pw
         WHERE USERS.USERNAME = p_username;
    ELSE
        RETURN < error message > ;
    END IF;
END CHANGE_PWD;
```

Comment: Ouch... passwords should never be stored.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option.

First, a test table:

```
SQL> create table users
  2    (username varchar2(30),
  3     password varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into users values ('LITTLEFOOT', '2cellos');

1 row created.
```

The procedure; I'd suggest you to return a string, not a Boolean (it's easier to work with it):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure change_pwd
  2    (p_username   in users.username%type,
  3     p_old_pw     in users.password%type,
  4     p_new_pw     in users.password%type,
  5     p_success   out varchar2
  6    )
  7  is
  8    l_old_pw  users.password%type;
  9  begin
 10    select password
 11      into l_old_pw
 12      from users
 13      where username = p_username;
 14
 15    if l_old_pw = p_old_pw then
 16       -- OK, old password matches
 17       update users set
 18         password = p_new_pw
 19         where username = p_username;
 20       p_success := 'Password changed';
 21    else
 22       p_success := 'Invalid old password';
 23    end if;
 24  exception
 25    when no_data_found then
 26      p_success := 'Invalid username';
 27  end;
 28  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_succ varchar2(100);
  3  begin
  4    change_pwd('LITTLEFOOT', 'xyz', 'newpwd', l_succ);
  5    dbms_output.put_line(l_succ);
  6
  7    change_pwd('bigFOOT', 'abc', 'newpwd', l_succ);
  8    dbms_output.put_line(l_succ);
  9
 10    change_pwd('LITTLEFOOT', '2cellos', 'newpwd', l_succ);
 11    dbms_output.put_line(l_succ);
 12  end;
 13  /
Invalid old password
Invalid username
Password changed

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have some errors

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHANGE_PWD (P_USERNAME IN USERS.USERNAME %TYPE,                                         
                                    P_OLD_PW   USERS.PASSWORD%TYPE,                                     
                                    P_NEW_PW IN USERS.PASSWORD %TYPE, 
                                    P_SUCCES OUT BOOLEAN ) IS
 VC_OLD_PW   USERS.PASSWORD%TYPE;

 BEGIN

    SELECT U.PASSWORD 
      INTO VC_OLD_PW 
      FROM USERS U
     WHERE U.USERNAME = p_username;

   /*Validate old pass*/
   IF VC_OLD_PW = USERS.PASSWORD THEN
      UPDATE USERS
         SET PASSWORD = p_new_pw
       WHERE USERS.USERNAME = p_username;
       COMMIT;
      --Ok change
      P_SUCCES   := TRUE;
   ELSE 
      --Change fail
      P_SUCCES  := FALSE;
      --RETURN <error message>; //This is unnecesary    
   END IF;

EXCEPTION
//Any exception
WHEN OTHERS THEN    
    P_SUCCES  := FALSE;   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error in procedure CHANGE_PWD '||SQLERRM)
END CHANGE_PWD;
```

You need study a little more about this, but that is normal.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I forgot about the variables in particular, that really helps!